# MSP430 Real time clock (RTC_B) doesn't work. Cannot write date/time registers

Tags: microcontroller, msp430, texas-instruments, real-time-clock

I'm trying to set date/time registers using the RTC_B module of MSP430F5338 microcontroller.
I'm doing it like this:

```
RTCCTL0 = 0;
RTCCTL1 |= RTCHOLD +RTCBCD;
RTCHOUR = 0x14;
RTCCTL1  &= ~RTCHOLD;
```

It doesn't work, and simply ignore the assignements. I cannot understand why. The only strange thing I've noticed is the `RTCOFIFG` flag set.

Any idea?

**Addendum**

This is how I set up clock sources:

```
void clk_init(){
  SetVcoreUp (0x01);
  SetVcoreUp (0x02);
  SetVcoreUp (0x03);

  UCSCTL3 = SELREF_2;                       // Set DCO FLL reference = REFO
  UCSCTL4 |= SELA_2;                        // Set ACLK = REFO

  __bis_SR_register(SCG0);                  // Disable the FLL control loop
  UCSCTL0 = 0x0000;                         // Set lowest possible DCOx, MODx
  UCSCTL1 = DCORSEL_7;                      // Select DCO range 50MHz operation
  UCSCTL2 = FLLD_1 | ((f_SMCLK/f_ACLK) -1);                   // Set DCO Multiplier for 25MHz
                                            // (N + 1) * FLLRef = Fdco
                                            // (762 + 1) * 32768 = 25MHz
                                            // Set FLL Div = fDCOCLK/2
  __bic_SR_register(SCG0);                  // Enable the FLL control loop


  // Loop until XT1,XT2 & DCO stabilizes - In this case only DCO has to stabilize
  do{
    UCSCTL7 &= ~(XT2OFFG | XT1LFOFFG | DCOFFG);
                                            // Clear XT2,XT1,DCO fault flags
    SFRIFG1 &= ~OFIFG;                      // Clear fault flags
  }while (SFRIFG1&OFIFG);                   // Test oscillator fault flag

}

void SetVcoreUp (unsigned int level)
{
  // Open PMM registers for write
  PMMCTL0_H = PMMPW_H;
  // Set SVS/SVM high side new level
  SVSMHCTL = SVSHE | SVSHRVL0 * level | SVMHE | SVSMHRRL0 * level;
  // Set SVM low side to new level
  SVSMLCTL = SVSLE | SVMLE | SVSMLRRL0 * level;
  // Wait till SVM is settled
  while ((PMMIFG & SVSMLDLYIFG) == 0);
  // Clear already set flags
  PMMIFG &= ~(SVMLVLRIFG | SVMLIFG);
  // Set VCore to new level
  PMMCTL0_L = PMMCOREV0 * level;
  // Wait till new level reached
  if ((PMMIFG & SVMLIFG))
    while ((PMMIFG & SVMLVLRIFG) == 0);
  // Set SVS/SVM low side to new level
  SVSMLCTL = SVSLE | SVSLRVL0 * level | SVMLE | SVSMLRRL0 * level;
  // Lock PMM registers for write access
  PMMCTL0_H = 0x00;
}
```

Comment: Are you really trying to set the hour to dec 34 (hex 22), and set the year to dec 8211 (hex 2013)?  I'm guessing it's refusing to set something to 34 hours...

Comment: You're right, but now I've set RTCHOUR = 0x0A and it still not working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've SOLVED adding this before clock setup:

```
 while (BAKCTL & LOCKBAK) BAKCTL &= ~LOCKBAK;
```

Basically this is due to the fact that msp430f5338 has the battery backup system, so you'll need this code before you set XT1 drive ACLK.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Having just had a browse through the datasheet - two things:

1. By setting the `RTCBCD` flag in `RTCCTL1`, you're saying you want to use binary-coded decimal, so setting `RTCHOUR` as `0x0A` is nonsense. To write proper BCD for, say, 14:47 (2:47pm), you write the hours as `0x14` and `0x47` as the minutes, i.e., write as you see.
2. Ensure you're not in low power mode 5 (LPM5) - configuration settings are not retained.

**Addendum:**

Also, the `RTCOFIFG` flags says you had a fault with your oscillator, so confirm your circuitry too.

Comment: Ok, I've corrected `RTCHOUR` value, but it still not works. I'll go for circuitry checking, as you suggested.

Comment: Apparently, there is no circuitry error. I've tested the code with the official development board.

Comment: Presuming you're using an external 32kHz crystal, are you actually driving it? Can you put a scope on it and see it oscillate?

Comment: Also, are those lines that you've written above actually being executed by the debugger - they're not optimized out or anything equally daft?

Comment: - I've added my set up for clock sources.

- No, I do not perform any optimization.

Comment: I have the same issue.  Internal RTC fails to lock.  One peculiarity is that the RTC locks when using the MSP430 debuggger (MSP-FET430UIF)